# Shell redirection doesn't move file position for stdout

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, posix

I have a minimal complete example where the Linux API behavior seems to be a bit ambiguous. The stdout is closed, reopened and used as a regular file's descriptor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
     system("echo > testfile");
     fclose(stdout);
     int fd = open("testfile", O_WRONLY);
     if (fd < 0) {
          perror("open():");
          return -1;
     }

     dprintf(fd, "Test\n");
     system("echo Test2");
     system("echo TestFFFFFFFFFFFF >> /proc/$$/fd/1"); // problem line
     sleep(5);
     dprintf(fd, "Test4\n");
     system("echo Test5");

     return 0;
}
```

Before sleep in `testfile` I see

```
Test
Test2
TestFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

But after sleep this line is overwritten:

```
Test
Test2
Test4
Test5
FFFF
```

It seems that for regular files this behavior is strange: if we write something to file - we change its position an appropriate way (to the end).
But for `stdout` it looks quite reasonable: if we write to `stdout` - we rewind its position back after finish writing (to the start).
Is this a bug or the right way?

P.S. Besides the `bash` I also tried `dash` and `ksh` - the same thing.

Comment: Where is the ambiguity? `It seems that for regular files this behavior is strange: if we write something to file - we change its position an appropriate way` Yes, and it happens. Why would a _separate process_ doing `>> /proc/$$/fd/1` change the file position of _your process_ fd?

Comment: @K because Test2 and Test5 did, I suppose.

Comment: @KamilCuk You mean that `system` spawns a new process. Ok, so both Test2 and Test5 are from spawned processes. So what is the difference? Is that the file descriptors  inheritance issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is:

> Is this a bug or the right way?

It is the right way.

---

`/proc/$$/fd/1` is a symlink to `testfile`, so `>> /proc/$$/fd/1` is the same as `>> testfile`. It is a separate child process that writes to `testfile`. When this child process terminates, you see the stuff it has written in the file. It has no effect on your parent process.

`STDOUT_FILENO` is not special, it's just like any other file descriptor.

Why child processes affect your parent process file descriptor position? Because `dup`licated file descrip**tors** *refer* to the *same open* file descrip**tion**. Read it twice - "file descriptor" != "file description". It is like a double-mapping. We say, file descrip**tors** are not copied, they are *duplicated*, they *share* the file offset and file status flags, because they share the file descrip**tion**. See `man 2 dup` and `man 2 open`.

When a separate process opens the same file, it has a separate file description, so it does not affect your process file description.

(It is so badly named. I mentally call "file descriptor" like "system handle" (because it can refer to *anything* kernel wants to) and call "file description" like "file data" (if it's a file, it can be anything kernel wants to). It's then clear - this "system handle" refers to this "file data" and "system handle" is duplicated between processes that means that two "system handles" refer to the same open "file data". And "file data" stores file position and file locks and such. Processes have "handles", not "data". "File data" are removed automatically, when the last "system handle" is getting removed (the confusing `man 2 unlink`).)